# Datetimepicker script

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I'm working on my way to write most efficient, reusable and robust code, and this is why I'd like to receive some support. I've written a datetimepicker script that allows datetime chosing, and a shortcut button that will subtract from higher date (the right input) a variable number of minutes:

Is there a way to simplify my code even more?

```
<form> 
  <input type="text" name="poczatek" id="od" /> 
  <input type="text" name="koniec" id="do" /> 
  <input type="button" value="10" class="odejmijCzas"/> 
  <input type="button" value="20" class="odejmijCzas"/> 
  <input type="button" value="30" class="odejmijCzas"/> 
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
dateTimeFormat = new Object();
dateTimeFormat.dwucyfrowa = function(m) {
    return m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
}
dateTimeFormat.format = function(date) {
    return date.getFullYear() + '-' + dateTimeFormat.dwucyfrowa(date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + dateTimeFormat.dwucyfrowa(date.getDate()) + ' ' + dateTimeFormat.dwucyfrowa(date.getHours()) + ':' + dateTimeFormat.dwucyfrowa(date.getMinutes());
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    inputOd = $("#od");
    inputDo = $("#do");

    inputOd.add(inputDo).datetimepicker({
        changeMonth: 'true'
    });

    currentTime = new Date();
    inputOd.add(inputDo).val(dateTimeFormat.format(currentTime));

    $('.odejmijCzas').click(function() {
        odejmijCzas($(this).attr('value'));
    });
});

function odejmijCzas(liczbaMinut) {
    czasDo = new Date(inputDo.val());
    roznicaCzasu = czasDo.getTime() - liczbaMinut * 1000 * 60;
    czasOd = new Date();
    czasOd.setTime(roznicaCzasu);
    inputOd.val(dateTimeFormat.format(czasOd));
}​
```

Comment: Are you having a problem with your code?

Comment: no it's working fine, but i'm wondering if i can shorten it even more

Comment: Well this is programming question, i want to know if i can make the code shorter

Comment: one great way to improve it - is not to use Polish for variable names

Answer (score 2):

A quick review:

**High Level Overview**

This code is okay except for 2 major items: you are not declaring your variables, making them escape all scope. And you use non-English variable names and function names, not every developer speaks Polish, though we should all understand English.

**Naming**

- English is the one true language for naming, please find English equivalents for `odejmijCzas`, `roznicaCzasu` etc.

**Idioms and Custom**

- Do not use `= new Object();`, use `= {}`

**Scope**

- You must declare everything with `var`, `let`, or `const`
- I would declare `dateTimeFormat` and `odejmijCzas` inside `$(document).ready(function() {` to keep the namespace clean

**[JSHint.com](http://jshint.com/)**

- Consider using http://jshint.com/ to perfect your code, most of these items were found by this tool as well